# Asking a more concise revision of a previously asked question

Tags: discussion, designer-reasons

I assume the Meta is the correct place to ask such a thing. I hope the question  itself is generic enough to get an answer that isn't too specific to my example, but I think I can better explain it using my example.

A while ago, I asked a [question about blowguns](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98744/35259), which in retrospect was quite broad, but as comments and answers came in, I started to realise that the part of the issue I had with blowguns was only a very specific aspect of what I had originally outlined - the martial proficiency.

I tried to cut the question down, but by that point, it had already gained a lot of clutter (although some of the comments have since disappeared) regarding various answers to the original version of the question, and the question itself still containing details from the original version of the question (since I didn't want to render any existing answers completely irrelevant, especially since they helped me realise this one aspect that I didn't like).

So, I want to ask a new question about the martial proficiency aspect specifically, ideally with a [designer-reasons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designer-reasons) tag, since I think that is the only way to get such an answer. Although I'll probably reference my old question, the new question will ask only about this one aspect.

**Should I ask a question that is a refined version of an existing question?** Or more specifically, should I ask this question about blowguns that is more specific that my previous question about blowguns?

If anyone has an opinion about if I should ask this specific question, I assume that's fine to include in the answer, but I'm guessing it's best for a more generic answer to be included as well (for example, someone might answer with "Yes, that's alright to do generally because ... but no, the specific question you want to ask about blowguns wouldn't be good because ...")? However, I'm obviously not expecting answers that talk about blowguns or proficiencies.

Comment: If the text of some of the now-gone comments would help you post this question, an elected moderator can find and reproduce them--just let us know.

Comment: @nitsua60 Thanks, but from memory the most helpful comment was one pointing out the difference between blowgun needles and throwing darts, which I added to the question to try to eliminate that aspect from future answers (i.e. that I originally thought blowguns might not be so weak if they did d4 damage like darts). Since I captured that in the question, I don't think the comment itself would be all that useful now. Also, I was mostly mentioning the comments here to make the point that the question overall had gained a lot of clutter that it was then being weighed down with, even if rewritten.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask away. If the answers provided to your general question have allowed you to formulate a more specific question then that is a different question.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem in asking.

And even if the community rules it is not a different question, we will just close the least-quality one and create a link to the highest-quality question.

When I state "least-quality one" does not imply the question can't be upvoted. If it is a well asked question, it deserves upvotes even if it is a dupe. And the other way around too.

There is no problem in posting duplicates. The alternate wording helps people searching for those terms to find their answer.

And making people find their answers is what the stack is all about.